# Trouble accessing GUI components from another thread. Dispatcher still throwing exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, action, dispatcher

I have a window that is subscribing to an event that is raised by an object.  I'm subscribing to the event as follows:

```
m_Monitor.NewJob += new Monitor.NewJobEvent(NewJobEventHandler);
```

The event is being raised successfully and is calling my NewJobEventHandler just fine.  The problem occurs when I try to make changes to any UI elements in the window.  I get the follow exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:  {"The calling thread
>   cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}

I've had this issue before and I've used some "Dispatcher" with some "Action" to get around it.  I'll admit that whole thing seem like magic to me and I really didn't understand it, but it did get me past the issue.  Coming from a C++ background I'm a bit miffed that I can't access certain things because they are in different threads.  But anyways, my NewJobEventHandler() routine is as follows:

```
private void NewJobEventHandler(JobInfo newJob)
{
    TreeViewItem tvItem = new TreeViewItem();
    tvItem.Header = "Job: " + newJob.ToString();

    //The following call is what causes the exception, yet I've used very
    //similar code to update the .Text property of a TextBox from another
    //thread
    OutputDataTree.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() => { OutputDataTree.Items.Add(tvItem); }));
}
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the `TreeViewItem` in the worker thread, but use it in the UI thread. You'll have to create it in the `Action`.

```
private void NewJobEventHandler(JobInfo newJob)
{
    TreeViewItem tvItem = new TreeViewItem();
    string header = "Job: " + newJob.ToString();

    //The following call is what causes the exception, yet I've used very
    //similar code to update the .Text property of a TextBox from another
    //thread
    OutputDataTree.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() => { 
                                  TreeViewItem tvItem = new TreeViewItem();
                                  tvItem.Header = header;
                                  OutputDataTree.Items.Add(tvItem); 
                               }));
}
```

This is of concern for any UI element you create, they need to be created in the UI thread to be useable.

Comment: Booya!  There it is. That "Action" syntax gets more and more magical to me.  I didn't know you could even have multiple statements in there.  Thanks.

Comment: A good read is the [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) page in msdn. Won't seem so magical after that.